# PySide methods signature in Eclipse/WingIDE/PyCharm?

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, pyside, pycharm

Is there any way to have the signature of the methods of PySide classes in Eclipse, WingIDE, PyCharm or any Python IDE?
Currently, it auto-completes the classes and method names, but not the parameters of the methods.
All functions are detected as functions without parameters.
[image: Eclipse PySide Screenshot]

I know it's a Python binding of a C++ framework so it's not that easy but is there any way to have the method signatures directly in an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I use [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) (Eclipse plugin) and it works like a charm, also with function signatures.

**EDIT:**

I'm not 100% sure with C++ extensions, but it should work well if there's a Python wrapper for it. With pure C++ extensions there *might* be problems, but actually I haven't tried it.

Comment: Have you tried with PySide?
The signatures work with other libraries, but not with PySide for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try running help(some-qt-method) in a Python console, what do you see? Exactly.

As far as I know, the only IDE that handles PyQt / PySide in depth is Eric, and only because it explicitly compiles signatures in its own format for autocompletion.